# Apex decrytion error: "System.SecurityException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption."

Tags: apex, javascript, encryption, decrypt

I am having some problem implementing a decryting function using a secret key and hash iv. I have a working code snippet in java script, but when I try to implement the function in apex, I get this error "System.SecurityException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption." whenever I try to decrypt the encrypted data. The key is "3yV3HckBVLvNUCqu0q8eFr8h7p4lJVXv" and hash iv is "PikRxB1LcCIhc3DC". I am pretty sure these are correct because the Javascript can decodes perfectly. However, the encryption of the data is not in my control, it is from another outside source. They only provided the key and the hash iv.

Here is the Javascript version:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("{!$Label.Hash_Key}");
            var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("{!$Label.Hash_IV}");
            
            var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
                ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(str)
            });
            console.log(cipherParams);
            var decryptedFromText = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams, key, { iv: iv });
            console.log('decryptedFromText ' + decryptedFromText.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
            var decodedTxt = decryptedFromText.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
            
            return decodedTxt;
```

and here is my apex code:

```
public static string DecryptData(string inputMethod, string inputKey, string inputIV, string inputData){
        string returnString = '';
        try {
            Blob CryptoKey = blob.valueof(inputKey);
            Blob CryptoIV = blob.valueof(inputIV);
            Blob EncryptedData;
            Blob DecryptedData;
            system.debug('data in string'+inputData);
            EncryptedData = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(inputData);
            system.debug('data in blob'+EncryptedData);
            DecryptedData = Crypto.decrypt(inputMethod, CryptoKey, CryptoIV, EncryptedData);
            system.debug('decrypteddata'+DecryptedData);
            returnString = DecryptedData.tostring();
            system.debug('decrypteddata returnString'+returnString);
        } catch (exception ex) {
            system.debug(ex.getMessage());
            returnString = 'DecryptError';
        }
        
        return returnString;
    }
```

And here is one of the encrypted string we are trying to decrypt: "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"

and the decrypted message should be something like:
{"Status":"SUCCESS","Message":"\u59d4\u8a17\u55ae\u6210\u7acb\uff0c\u4e14\u9996\u6b21\u6388\u6b0a\u6210\u529f","Result":{"MerchantID":"MS3536051697","MerchantOrderNo":"RG_00038028_1672227403323","PeriodType":"Y","PeriodAmt":"15000","AuthTimes":5,"DateArray":"2022-12-28,2023-12-28,2024-12-28,2025-12-28,2026-12-28","TradeNo":"22122819394834062","AuthCode":"669485","RespondCode":"00","AuthTime":"20221228193947","CardNo":"515713******2904","EscrowBank":"HNCB","AuthBank":"Taishin","PeriodNo":"P221228193947alb5na"}}

This is my first time posting on this platform. Let me know if I am doing anything I shouldn't be and I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi, and welcome here! If you haven't yet, please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick 2 minute [tour]. Your post is already pretty decent, especially for a first question. You'll also want to take a look at our [expected behavior](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), particularly, you don't need to express gratitude (it's assumed here) and you don't need to mention that you're new (we all see the "Ethan Lin is a new contributor" banner). Aside from that, lots of detail. I'm sure we'll be able to get you an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String encrypted using Crypto js can not decrypted via Crypto apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369879/string-encrypted-using-crypto-js-can-not-decrypted-via-crypto-apex)

Comment: You didn't show how you're encrypting it in JS but no matter, follow the referenced Q&A.

Comment: @sfdcfox I will take a look.

Comment: @identigral All of the stuff you removed in your edit significantly changes the question. For example, I found that in Apex, it's 64 bytes shorter than the JS code. This is a significant clue that might help solve the problem.

Comment: @identigral I took a quick look and tried but it's still giving me the same error "System.SecurityException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption." I cannot know how they are encrypting the data since it is from another outside source and they wouldn't tell me.

Comment: @sfdcfox that might be the problem, can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @EthanLin You have to encrypt in exactly the way the referenced Q&A shows you.

Comment: @identigral yeah that will work but the provider wouldn't change how they are encrypting the data for me.

Comment: @EthanLin Please edit your question and show what the provider is doing

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix the problem, but I'll say this: Apex only supports a limited number of encryption configurations, so if they can't change it, you may be stuck. See the [Crypto](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) docs for supported encryption modes.

Comment: yes I think I will have to think of another way. Either setting up an api to decrypt for me, or find a way to call the javascript in apex.

Comment: @EthanLin Or rethink the need for encryption. Quite often, encryption is a sign of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as it doesn't solve a problem one might be trying to solve.